# How do one get current connection from SQL Editor document in a SSMS 2018 extension in C#

Tags: c#, ssms

Before, it has been possible to use something like...

```
var scriptFactory = ServiceCache.ScriptFactory;
var connectionInfo = scriptFactory.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo;
var conn = connectionInfo.UIConnectionInfo;
```

Now I am completely lost about how to get the connection that is used by the active document. Does anyone have any idea of how to do something similiar? Or should it still work but I just failed to do so?

Comment: Did you find answer for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var scriptFactory = ServiceCache.ScriptFactory;
var connectionInfo = scriptFactory.CurrentlyActiveWndConnectionInfo;
var conn = connectionInfo.UIConnectionInfo;
```

This is still working, you just have to add the correct dll files to access it.
If you look in your SSMS Programs folder you can copy dll files for Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectionInfo.dll and SqlPackageBase.dll